# Producing XML Output in Web Service

Tags: java, xml, web-services, jaxb

A bit new to working with Web Services but I'm having an issue displaying output correctly.  I'm attempting to use JAXB to generate my XML but I don't know how to pass that back to the Web Service correctly for consumption by the client.

I have my main class that I generated by web service from named Client.  I have a method (ReturnClientData) that will go into my database and retrieve some information for me.  Within that method I call a procedure to create the xml:

```
@XmlRootElement(name = "client")
public class ClientDataJAXB {

private String clientName;
private String clientPhone;

public void setClientName(String value) {
    this.clientName = value;
}
@XmlElement(name = "clientName")
public String getClientName() { return clientName; }
.....
```

So my question is: since the ReturnClientData method is called by the web service, how do I provide proper feedback for all my fields so they are displayed correctly?  What's the return type in this case?  Can I mashal out to the web service somehow?  I'm testing the client side from SoapUI.

Comment: Is your web interface expecting the raw XML in a file?

Comment: No, not in a file.  If I pass it an individual string containing one item it will create a node in the XML.  If I send back a string array list I get:  <soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
   <soapenv:Body>
      <certifyResponse xmlns="http://client.result.com">
         <certifyReturn xsi:type="xsd:string">0</certifyReturn>
         <certifyReturn xsi:type="xsd:string">4132453915</certifyReturn>
      </certifyResponse> ...

Comment: Nevermind, I resolved it.  I had to pass back the JAXB object I created (ClientDataJAXB).  Once I did that the web service was able to produce the correct XML output.

Comment: @user3306212 - Can you add your solution as a real answer?